Get all users of specified groups from Tableau Server using TableauServerClient
I would like to get a list of all users for 3 AD groups on our Tableau server site using the TSC package. Based on some resources out there, I have the below using Python.
The first snippet of code returns all users on our site and exports the list to an Excel. The second snippet is my attempt to apply a filter that returns just the users in the 3 AD groups, but it returns 0 users.
Our site uses AD groups to provision access. I need to validate whether the members of these 3 groups have access to the data source the dashboard uses. The plan is to get the list of users from Tableau server and merge the group list with the list of users with access to the data source to return an output that would flag instances where I get a left only in _merge.
Any input would be much appreciated.
Returns all users on site.
import tableauserverclient as TSC
import pandas as pd

tableau_auth = TSC.PersonalAccessTokenAuth('My_Dashboard_Update','access-token-xyz',site_id = 'site-name') 
server = TSC.Server('https://tableau-site/',use_server_version=True)

with server.auth.sign_in(tableau_auth):

  request_options = TSC.RequestOptions(pagesize=1000)

  all_users, pagination_item = server.users.get(request_options)

  

  print("\nThere are {} user on site: ".format(pagination_item.total_available))

  all_users_on_site = pd.DataFrame({'Users': [user.name for user in all_users]})

  all_users_on_site.to_excel(r"C:\\Users\TABLEAU_User_ME\Documents\Projects\Tableau_Users.xlsx", index = False)

Modified to filter on 3 groups; returns 0 users.
import tableauserverclient as TSC
import pandas as pd

tableau_auth = TSC.PersonalAccessTokenAuth('My_Dashboard_Update','access-token-xyz',site_id = 'site-name') 
server = TSC.Server('https://tableau-server-site/',use_server_version=True)

with server.auth.sign_in(tableau_auth):

    request_options = TSC.RequestOptions(pagesize=1000)
    request_options.filter.add(TSC.Filter(TSC.RequestOptions.Field.Name, 
                                          TSC.RequestOptions.Operator.In,
                                          ["AD-Group1","AD-Group2", "AD-Group3"],)         
        )
    matching_groups, pagination_item = server.users.get(request_options)
    
    print("\nThere are {} user on site: ".format(pagination_item.total_available))
    all_users_on_site = pd.DataFrame({'Users': [user.name for user in matching_groups]})

  all_users_on_site.to_excel(r"C:\\Users\TABLEAU_User_ME\Documents\Projects\Tableau_Users.xlsx", index = False)


Why not use the GroupItem class to return the users of the group?

That was helpful @MUFF.

Here's the final edit to get all users. The comment from MUFF was helpful. Thanks!
import tableauserverclient as TSC
import pandas as pd

tableau_auth = TSC.PersonalAccessTokenAuth('My_Dashboard_Update','access-token-xyz',site_id = 'site-name') 
server = TSC.Server('https://tableau-site/',use_server_version=True)

with server.auth.sign_in(tableau_auth):

    request_options = TSC.RequestOptions(pagesize=1000)
    request_options.filter.add(TSC.Filter(TSC.RequestOptions.Field.Name, 
                                          TSC.RequestOptions.Operator.In,
                                          ["AD-Group1","AD-Group2", "AD-Group3"],)         
        )

    all_groups, pagination_item = server.groups.get(request_options)
    
    all_users, pagination_item = server.users.get(request_options)
    mygroup2 = all_groups[1]
    
    pagination_item = server.groups.populate_users(mygroup2)
    
    #list of all users in AD groups with IDs
    for user in mygroup2.users:
        all_users_on_site = pd.DataFrame({'Users': [user.name for user in mygroup2.users],
                                           'id': [user.id for user in mygroup2.users]
                                           })  


Glad the comment was helpful. Just an additional note; when building your variable all_users_on_site why are you nesting for loops for each user and id if you are already have the user in your initial for loop? all_users_on_site = pd.DataFrame({'Users': [user.name], 'id': [user.id]})

I'm a big time python noob. Had tried variations of the code based on what I gathered on the web so no concrete reason, but I'm trying and learning!

does it have to use tableauserverclient and in python ?
Otherwise, you can query the Tableau repository ( after enabling access to it ) to it, for similar results.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
